# Jupyterhub does not run through plist

Tags: macos, http-proxy, jupyterhub

I have been running **jupyterhub 0.91**. in a MacOS Sierra (Version 10.12.6) successfully and could access the notebook from any client connected to this MacOS network. I attempted to make **jupyterhub** as a service. Towards this, I created the **org.xyz.jupyter.plist** file in **/Users/xyz/Library/LaunchAgents** (**xyz** is my user ID) with the following contents (standard header and footer info omitted for brevity):

```
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.xyz.jupyter</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/xyz/Library/LaunchAgents/jupyterhub.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/jupyterhub.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/jupyterhub.out</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

And, the contents of **/Users/xyz/Library/LaunchAgents/jupyterhub.sh** are:

```
PID=$(pgrep -f jupyterhub)
if [ "x$PID" = "x" ]; then # Ensure only one jupyterhub instance is running
    sudo /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/jupyterhub -f /Users/Shared/jupyterhub_config.py
fi
```

I ran the above shell script independently and **jupyterhub** started without posing any problems. However, when I restarted my Mac to auto start the hub, I got the following error (excerpts):

```
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'configurable-http-proxy': 'configurable-http-proxy'
```

I checked the location **/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/** from where **jupyterhub** is executed and found the file **configurable-http-proxy**. Then, I copied it to: **/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6** from where the subprocess.py is executing and reporting the absence of **configurable-http-proxy**. Still, the error remains the same. Any help, please?

Answer (score 2):

When the agent to start **jupyterhub** is run, it does not seem to have any idea about the executables' locations. In this case, it does not know where **configurable-http-proxy** is resident. So, I added an **EnvironmentVariables** directive that contains the path (**/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin**) for the above file. The revised **plist** file is:

```
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.xyz.jupyter</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/jupyterhub</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>/Users/Shared/jupyterhub_config.py</string>
    </array>
```

Rest of things as shown in my question.